# Getting response back to GUI from netty

Tags: user-interface, javafx, netty

I have multiple controllers that handles my GUI(javaFX) changes (one for each page).
I have a handler for my netty client.

The way that I have it setup right now is when my GUI initializes, I start a new thread that runs my netty client and assign it with reference to my GUI controllers.

Essentially, my GUI controller sends request using netty handler, and then when netty handler receives response, it tells GUI controller to update the GUI components.

It works fine right now but it's starting to become messing as I add more controllers in.

Are there any standard ways of setting up javaFX with Netty?

Comment: Instead of passing references to the controllers to the netty client and having the client invoke methods on the controllers, consider passing callbacks (typically implemented as [`Consumer`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) to the client. Have a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javafxinteg-2062777.html, which may give you some ideas.